# removing borders around twitter widget

Tags: html, css, twitter, widget

I've managed to manipulate most of the twitter widget's css but I can't seem to remove the black border around the whole widget and there seems to be a much thicker border on the bottom of the widget which I also want to remove. I'm using Chrome to test this.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvTdb/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "border" is actually a background color which is shining through because you have a 1px padding on `.twtr-bd`, so the background color of `.twtr-bd` is not erasing the black background from the parent element.

Either remove the background color, or remove the padding.

Answer (score 1):

give `backgeound-color:white` like this:

```
#twtr-widget-1 .twtr-new-results, #twtr-widget-1 .twtr-results-inner, #twtr-widget-1 .twtr-timeline {
    background:#FFFFFF !important;
}
```